# How to avoid double google indexing using .htaccess?

Tags: html, .htaccess, indexing, robots.txt

I have a website, with a nice RewriteRule in its root, that redirects all the queries of this kind:

```
http://domain.com/foo/parameter
```

into

```
http://domain.com/index.php?args=parameter
```

Users can only see the clean URL and everyone is happy.

Now here is the problem: domain.com DNS have an A record for domain.com, pointing to a private server IP, and an A record for mail.domain.com, pointing to the exact same IP.

For some unknown reason, in the last couple of months, Google double indexed all the pages of my site (`http://domain.com/foo/par1`, `http://domain.com/foo/par2` etc.) with another set with the mail subdomain (`http://mail.domain.com/foo/par1`, `http://mail.domain.com/foo/par2` etc).

I thought I could get rid of all of them redirecting any request to mail.domain.com/$whatever to domain.com and eventually Google would understand that all those pages with the 'mail' subdomain redirects to the homepage and are therefore not necessary.

I tried this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com [R=301,L]
```

But this redirects to a visible URL that looks like this: `http://domain.com/index.php?args=parameter`, while I just want a redirect to the homepage.

What's the correct form, and are there more elegant ways to achieve this, maybe adding something into robots.txt? (Please note that I can't just disallow a subfolder here)

Comment: This might be a better fit for webmasters.SE or even serverfault.com.

Comment: `.htaccess` questions are asked here all the time, so I think it's accepted.

Comment: @nitro2k01 - Just because they are asked here, doesn't mean they should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to redirect to home page by discarding the original REQUEST_URI and QUERY_STRING then use these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/? [R=301,L]
```

By putting `?` in the end it will strip out original query string, thus a URL of this type: `http://mail.domain.com/index.php?args=parameter` will become `http://domain.com/`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I missed the question mark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your rule is correct, but you need to put it before all the other rules (right after `RewriteEngine On`) or it will pick up the latest state of the internal rewritten URL.

Update: Hmm, you said that your old rule redirects correctly but is using the internal, ugly, URL. That actually shouldn't be the case unless you add `$1` to pick out the matched string.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```